# What do the f and t commands do in Vim?

Tags: vim

What do <kbd>f</kbd> and <kbd>t</kbd> commands do in vim and exactly how they work?

Answer (score 310, accepted):

Your first stop with questions like these should be vim's internal help, `:h f` and `:h t`.  However, in this case, those entries are a bit cryptic without an example.  Suppose we had this line (`^` = cursor position):

```
The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
^
```

These commands find characters on a line.  So `fb` would place the cursor here:

```
The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
          ^
```

`t` is like `f` but places the cursor on the preceding character.  So `tb` would give you:

```
The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
         ^
```

You can remember these commands as `f`ind and `t`ill.  Also, you can prepend the commands with a number to move to the nth occurrence of that character.  For example, `3fb` would move to the third b to the right of the cursor.  My example sentence only has one b though, so the cursor wouldn't move at all.

Comment: And if you write the letters in uppercase, then it jumps backward. So for example `Fb` or `Tb`.

Answer (score 168):

Just to add to [Michael Kristofik's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12495564/2071807), no description of `f` or `t` is complete without also mentioning <kbd>;</kbd>.

From [this Vim cheat sheet](http://www.fprintf.net/vimCheatSheet.html):

`;` "Repeat latest f, t, F or T [count] times."

So, to continue the @MichaelKristofik's theme:

```
The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
^
```

type `fo` to go to the first 'o':

```
The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
            ^
```

and then `;` to go to the next one:

```
The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
                 ^
```

Comment: the ; tip is pretty useful, though I don't see how it works with 't'. i tried and i am stuck in the same position no matter how many times the t command is repeated.

Comment: @PeterPerháč Press semicolon several times. Works for me.

Comment: @PeterPerháč, I guess it is trickier with the t command, since when searching forward for x, the semicolon will find the same x every time you hit ;, thus not moving. If you hit l once and then semicolon it should work.

Comment: @PeterPerháč Make sure you aren't already at (one character before) the last occurrence on the line, and it should find the next occurrence.

Answer (score 73):

I find <kbd>f</kbd> and <kbd>t</kbd> very useful in combination with <kbd>d</kbd> and <kbd>c</kbd>.  For example,  `ct:` will let you replace everything from your cursor up to the next colon, but not delete the colon.  You can remember it as "change to colon".

Comment: +1! Idioms like `ct,` or `ct)`to quickly replace one or last argument to a function call feel wonderful to use.

Comment: I prefer `vt:c` because you don't spot always spot each occurrence of a given letter 100% correct. With `v` you can see the visual selection, a nice visual cue.

Answer (score 39):

`fx` jumps to the *next* `x` on the line.

`tx` jumps to the character just before the *next* `x` on the line.

You can use `Fx` and `Tx` to reach the *previous* `x`.

You can use `2fx` to jump to the second `x` on the line.

So, `fF`and `tT` are useful when you want to go quickly to the next set of parentheses (`f(`) or delete everything from the cursor to, but excluding, the previous `=` (`dT=`) and so on…

See [`:h motion.txt`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/motion.html#motion.txt). It will blow your mind.

Comment: thanks for mentioning that `2fx` thing. I always confuse it with `f2x`

Answer (score 15):

Since LondonRob mentioned `;`, I guess a description of the comma `,` command is in order. It is used very much in conjunction with these commands (when the search overshoots).

After performing a search with `f`, `F`, `t` or `T`, one could use `,` to repeat the search in the opposite direction.

Let's say we are at the start of this sentence, and we would like to change the *elot* to *elit*.

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elot sed do eiusmod tempor.
^
```

I know I have to replace an *o*, so I perform an `fo` (find o) immediately. The cursor is stuck at some early *o* in the line! Hit `;` to repeat the search in the same direction. Type type type... I should have just done it five times, but let's say I overshoot and type `;` six times instead. I end up here:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elot sed do eiusmod tempor.
 ^ 
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elot sed do eiusmod tempor.
             ^ 
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elot sed do eiusmod tempor.
               ^ 
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elot sed do eiusmod tempor.
                            ^ 
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elot sed do eiusmod tempor.
                                                    ^ 
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elot sed do eiusmod tempor.
                                                            ^ 
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elot sed do eiusmod tempor.
                                                                   ^
```

Now, one could just perform a `,` twice to repeat this search in the other direction. The cursor will reach the *o* in *elot*.

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elot, sed do eiusmod tempor.
                                                              ^        
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elot, sed do eiusmod tempor.
                                                     ^
```

`ri` to finish the replacement.

As with most movement commands, `,` also take a count: `[count],`.

From the manual:

> Repeat latest f, t, F or T in opposite direction [count] times.