# Vim: move cursor to a character two spaces before another

Tags: regex, vim

Using vim search patterns, how would I set vim to move the cursor to a character that is two spaces to the left of another specified character? For instance, a character two spaces before the '=' sign.

Comment: `t=h`? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12495442/what-do-the-f-and-t-commands-do-in-vim

Comment: Thank you Hatchet, do you know if there is a way to do what I ask with the / search feature in vim? That is the answer I was hoping for.

Comment: Not that I know of, other than `hh` or `2h` after searching. Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

You can pass offsets to search patterns

```
/{pattern}/{offset}
```

For this case (two characters before =) you would want

```
/=/b-2
```

Would match the = signs and then put the cursor two characters before the beginning of the match (`/=/s-2` s for start would also work)

Take a look at `:h search-offset` (copied below)

```
                                        search-offset {offset}
These commands search for the specified pattern.  With "/" and "?" an
additional offset may be given.  There are two types of offsets: line offsets
and character offsets.  {the character offsets are not in Vi}

The offset gives the cursor position relative to the found match:
    [num]       [num] lines downwards, in column 1
    +[num]      [num] lines downwards, in column 1
    -[num]      [num] lines upwards, in column 1
    e[+num]     [num] characters to the right of the end of the match
    e[-num]     [num] characters to the left of the end of the match
    s[+num]     [num] characters to the right of the start of the match
    s[-num]     [num] characters to the left of the start of the match
    b[+num]     [num] identical to s[+num] above (mnemonic: begin)
    b[-num]     [num] identical to s[-num] above (mnemonic: begin)
    ;{pattern}  perform another search, see //;

If a '-' or '+' is given but [num] is omitted, a count of one will be used.
When including an offset with 'e', the search becomes inclusive (the
character the cursor lands on is included in operations).
```

Comment: If it matters, this information is easily found through the help pages. `:help /` brings you to the help for search. The second paragraph says you can pass an offset. If you then click `<c-]>` on the `{offset}` symbols it brings you to `:help search-offset`

Answer (score 1):

if you are in normal mode you can use this pattern :

```
/..=/
```

. refers to any character

Keep in mind that the cases below are not included in the pattern as there are not enough characters before '**=**' .

> |=
>
> |.=

with **.** (point) I refer to any character and with **|** the limit of the starting line.