# VS Code: jump to next occurrence of character x

Tags: visual-studio-code, vim, key-bindings

In Vim, you can press `fx` and `Fx` to move to the next and previous occurrence of x on the same line:

```
**fx** - jump to next occurrence of character x
**Fx** - jump to previous occurence of character x
```

source: https://vim.rtorr.com/

I don't wish to use a vim emulator in VS Code, I instead would like to bind `Ctrl+f` to forward search and `Ctrl+b` for backwards search.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I just posted an extension (I'm pretty sure you can't do it without an extension) that does what you want:  [Jump and Select](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ArturoDent.jump-and-select)

It does a little more than you want in case other people would like the selection option.  You can bind any keybinding to the commands you want.  The following demo uses <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>f</kbd> for forward and <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>b</kbd> for backward.

[image: Jump and Select demo]

Note that the key you want to go to is not displayed.  And you don't have to hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> to trigger the move - it just goes there immediately.  And it works with multiple cursors.

Also, I am not familiar with vim.  If you go back to some designated previous character, should the cursor end up before or after that character?  Right now it goes **to** that character (so the cursor is after it) but it is easy for me to make to change that behaviour in the extension.  Just let me know.

[image: multiMode jumping]

Comment: This is amazing!  I just tried your extension. Regarding: If you go back to some designated previous character, should the cursor end up before or after that character? It should go *before* the character, so your code would need updating. Also:  the search should be exclusive to the current line of the cursor. So it shouldn't move to other lines. Are you able to make these two changes? I will be so grateful.

Comment: I'll make the cursor placement change.  That is easy.  I'll probably make the restrict to the same line an option or just a different command.  I think a lot of people might want to go to the next brace/bracket/etc. wherever it is.

Comment: I just pushed the change to the cursor placement for previous characters.  It'll take a couple of minutes to be available on the Marketplace.  The other change will take a little longer.

Comment: I made a large update to this extension - check the default settings to make sure you have them how you want.

Comment: And check out `multiMode` jumping - you can really fly from chosen character to character.

Comment: The fact that it works on multi-line is awesome, I've been looking for that for so long. Thanks for bring it to reality @Mark!

Answer (score 3):

In VSCode, "find next" is performed by `Ctrl+G` (Cmd in MacOS) and "find previous" by `Ctrl+Shift+G`.

You can edit the keyboard shortcuts by going to `Code > Preferences > Keyboard Shortcuts` and looking for both "Find Next" and "Find Previous", and hovering over the keybinding to edit it to your preference.

[image]

Comment: This is not what I am requesting as this does not match the behaviour of Vim's `f` command. here is a description of vim's `f` command: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12495442/what-do-the-f-and-t-commands-do-in-vim/23223763

Comment: Just a quick explanation of the desired behavior I'd like: Hitting "ctrl+f f" should jump  to the next occurance of character "f" on the same line. Just a quick jump, without selecting it, without having to hit enter. This is have the `f` command in Vim works

Comment: Just a little note on using this: if you press `⌘ + G`, and then `f` the default search will already take you to the next `f` on the line (**before** you hit enter), but do have to hit  ⎋ (Escape) to exit out of the search.  So, if you want to go to the 4th `f` on the line, you can do `⌘ + G  f  ⏎   ⏎  ⏎   ⎋`.